# Redirecting to port 8080 if accessed by a certain domain

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, port, jboss

I am running Apache on port 80 of my server, and JBoss on port 8080 of the same machine. How can I have Apache redirect requests with a certain domain name to the JBoss server on 8080? I'd like to keep the port number from showing in the URLs for the JBoss site.. is an Apache rewrite the best way to  do this? Or should I use a different method / tool?

For example, requests to "x.com" would eventually lead the user to 1.2.3.4:80, while requests to "y.com" would bring them to 1.2.3.4:8080.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a [connector](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/config/ajp.html) in the virtual host instead of redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the *best* way but you could use mod_proxy to setup a [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

Virtual host is setup for y.com on 1.2.3.4:80 this would be proxied to 1.2.3.4:8080.